# Pouchdb Find Plugin - How to use this plugin with similar to SQL LIKE %abc%?

Tags: sql, pouchdb

I encounter problem to use **Pouchdb Find Plugin** to do something like **SQL LIKE %abc%** and with sorting.

May I know is there any possible way that can use like that?

```
var selector = {
    selector: {
        'name': {$like: 'David'},
        'age': {$gt: 0}
    },
    sort: [{'age': 'asc'}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$regex` matcher, and then have a regular expression like `'.*?abc.*?'`.

Keep in mind, though, that this query is *very inefficient* because it's not indexed; it's run in-memory. (The same is true of relational databases like MySQL/Postgres.) In general, you should only do prefix searches, not searches that look *inside* of the string, because then you need to scan the entire database to do so.

Comment: Yea, Will take note on that not to scan the entire database without prefix.

Thanks for the quick reply. It helps me a lot! :)